# Hbase completebulkload stuck on AWS EMR

Tags: hadoop, hbase, emr

So the scenario is I am trying to use HBase bulk load to load some data into HBase.
Here's my stack setting:
HBase version 1.3.1
Hadoop version: 2.7.3
EMR version 5.10.
Cluster size: 20 R4.2xlarge instances.
I have a hbase table which was pre-splitted into 400 regions with HexStringSplit for the row key.
The table contains only one column family and it used lz4 compression algorithm

I then tried to use bulkload to load some data into the table.
I was able to use import tsv tool to generate HFiles on HDFS, the total file size is about 20 GB.

Then I ran the "completebulkload" tool as follows:
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-server-1.3.1.jar completebulkload hdfs:///user/hbase/output MyTable

Here "hdfs:///user/hbase/output" is the output directory of the import tsv job.

The process started but got stuck, I only see following output:

```
17/12/05 19:49:22 WARN mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles: Skipping non-directory hdfs://ip-172-31-19-197.ec2.internal:8020/user/hbase/output/_SUCCESS
17/12/05 19:49:23 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.lz4]
17/12/05 19:49:23 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.lz4]
17/12/05 19:49:23 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.lz4]
17/12/05 19:49:23 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.lz4]
```

No further information was printed. It's been almost 1 hour but still nothing. I checked the HBase UI and nothing has been loaded yet. All regions are empty.

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks

Comment: Turned out I ran into hdfs permission issue, as shown below:Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=hbase, access=WRITE, inode="/user/tbw/oo/c/f0c6be43697c426790d0fa7c30ba6e73":hadoop:hadoop:drwxr-xr-x

Comment: The fix is to grant write permission to given hdfs location. For example: "hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /user/tbw/oo"